# Quick Blox. Start from scratch guide

Tags: ios, quickblox

Following tutorial does for me some error.

I used this 5 minutes [guide](http://quickblox.com/developers/5_Minute_Guide) to get my new app. I registered new app and copied all keys to the `AppDelegate` but now when I run app I get this error every new run app:

[image]

How to add new user to chat?

Added new user:

[image]

Modified password:

[image]

Comment: You should improve your title so more people can help.

Answer (score 1):

You should create user via Admin Panel or sign up with new user via code.
To be able to test users in our samples you should create user(or users) with tag "dev" and change `kTestUsersDefaultPassword` to the password you've chosen for user (For our samples we're retrieving users with tag `dev` and for this users we have similar password `kTestUsersDefaultPassword`. You can change this password in LoginVC).

Then:
1)To be able to use QuickBlox API you have to create a user and be signed in.

2)In order to use real time features you have to be logged in to Chat.

For more further explanation, please refer to [this link](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#A_few_words_about_Authentication_and_Authorization)

If you want to retrieve users not by tags please refer to [this link](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Retrieving_users)

Comment: thanks Vitaliy! I've updated my question with adding info you've provided, the same error yet.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander It is not allowed in settings of your application to download users http://admin.quickblox.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/settings
Check "Allow to retrieve a list of users